# Linux: Can I link multiple destinations via softlinks?

Tags: linux, command-line, file-management, symbolic-link

Attempting to end up with something similar to this:

```
$ ls -l  
lrwxrwxrwx  1 user group   4 Jun 28  2010 foo -> /home/bar  
lrwxrwxrwx  1 user group   4 Jun 29  2010 foo -> /etc/bar
```

The intention is to be able to move a file to foo & have it go to both destination directories for now.  The goal is to eventually unlink /home/bar link after confirming there are no issues with moving the files to /etc/bar.  I am restricted in that I am unable to change or add to the process that moves the files.

Comment: A little more detail about this 'process' which copies the files, and we might be able to dig up another solution for you.

Comment: The process is a vendor supplied perl script, which, because of company policy restrictions, can not be modified by anyone here.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

No, a link may resolve to one and only one file/folder.  More specifically, a folder may not contain more than one item with the same name, and the working directly would need to have two files named "foo" to do as you describe.

Comment: Two links to a single file named foo would have been more what I was looking for... I just used an arbitrary ls -l to try to show my desired result since I wasn't sure if a link could resolve to multiple files/folders.  Anyway, I'm accepting your answer based on the properties of links you are describing, which is what I was unsure of.

Comment: @kds1398: You can have multiple links to a single file: `foo -> baz` and `bar -> baz`.

Comment: @Dennis Williamson: My comment above was incorrect as I was looking for foo -> baz & foo -> bar in a single directory.

Answer (score 2):

A link can only point to one file, so you cannot have `foo` reference both `/home/bar` and `/etc/bar`. Depending on the nature of what you are trying to do, you may be able to accomplish your goal by having `foo -> /etc/bar` and then also set `/home/bar -> /etc/bar`.

Answer (score 1):

You can use a named pipe and a continuously running process that uses `tee` to make the output go to multiple files.

```
$ mkfifo foo
$ while :; do tee -a /home/bar /etc/bar < foo > /dev/null 2>&1; done &
$ echo hello > foo
$ cat /home/bar
hello
$ cat /etc/bar
hello
```

Answer (score 0):

Your best bet would probably be some kind of special moint on `foo`. I doubt that you can do this with just the mechanisms provided by the kernel (a union doesn't quite cover it ...), but it should be relatively easy to cook something up with fuse.